# Dual Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $f : V \to W$ is a linear transformation,  a linear transformation $f^* : L^k(W) \to L^k(V)$ is defined by  $$f^*T(v_1, \dots, v_k) = T(f(v_1), \dots, f(v_k))$$ for $T \in L^k(W)$ and $v_1 \dots v_k \in V.$
>
> Note that $L^k(W)$ denotes the set of all $k$ tensors on $W$ and we define $L^k(V)$ similiarly.

So to my understanding $f^*$ takes elements from $W^*$, the dual space of $W$ and sends those dements to the dual space of $V^*$. Now the elements of $W^*$ are linear functionals **on $W$**. So if $T$ really is a linear functional on $W$, why are we inputting a tuple of vectors from $V$ instead on the LHS? Also the output should be an element of $V^*$, yet the RHS is a linear functional on $W$ (because $T \in W^*_k$).

Comment: The reason $f^{*}T$ is a functional on $(V^{*})^N$ is because it takes the arguments/inputs $(v_1,v_2,..,v_k)$ and it is linear on each spot. This is the formal presentation of the pullback of an $n-form w$ by a linear map (usually the tangent map.)

Comment: Let me change my notation, sorry.

Comment: I think what I object to is to operating on a $k$ tuple of vectors, the functions involved all are unary.

Comment: You don't have to change it to $V_k^*$ and $W_k^*$. $V^*$ and $W^*$ are fine.

Comment: @M.Vinay, I guess it doesn't change my question very much.

Comment: Well now I am confused what do the $v_i$ denote ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I suppose user99680 got it right, $f$ is a multilinear map (like the determinant) and $v_i$ are vectors?

Comment: Too much confusion here. See my comment below.

Comment: You mean only *covariant* tensors of rank $k$ here, i.e., $k$-multilinear maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is not quite right $f^*(T)$ is an element of $V^*$ it acts on a vector $v \in V$ as follows: first it sends $v$ to $W$ via $f$ to get $f(v)$ and then it evaluates $T$ at this vector. So the defining equation is 
$$f^*(T)(v)=T(f(v)).$$

Comment: "Your notation is not quite right f∗(T) is an element of V∗ it acts on a vector v∈V as follows:" I see, that is a very strange definition indeed to me. So this immediately implies that this definition is ill-defined if $W$ and $V$ contain different ranks of tensors

Comment: Is $V_k$ the k th tensor product ? Why not define $f_k :V_k \rightarrow W_k$ first then use the general definition I give in my answer.

Comment: Actually I may have figured out my confusion. As you have indicated, the target space is the dual space of $V$, not a scalar field. If we (for some reason) define $f^*: W^*_k \to \mathbb{R}$, then it would make more sense to take vectors in $W$.

Comment: I know what the confusion is now, the LHS is just a symbol, the RHS is what the definition means. I took the LHS too seriously.

Answer (score 1):

From your notation you may be considering the dual of a *multilinear* , not just linear map. The map $$f^*T(v_1, \dots, v_k) = T(f(v_1), \dots, f(v_k))$$ you described is multilinear (linear in each component $v_i$ in $V_i$ ), and it seems to be defined as the dual of a multilinear map $$f: V\times V \times....\times V  \rightarrow W\times W....\times W$$ (  k times in both cases). Notice that this map is defined on the dual of $V^k$ because it takes $(v_1,v_2,..,v_k)$ as inputs. 
 The case $k=1$ is described above by Rene; notice how the map takes $v$ as an argument, so that it is an element of $V^*$. As an example of this induced map you have the case of the pullback of a differential k-form by a(n) EDIT linear map. This map is often the tangent map between the respective tangent spaces. Notice that both maps are contravariant, and that this induced map is a (contravariant, of course) functor between vector spaces .

Comment: It takes $k$ vectors from $V^K$, but isn't a problem if $\dim V \neq \dim W$? That is if $v_1 = (v_1^1, v_1^2) \in V$ and $w_1 = (w_1^1, w_1^2, w_1^3) \in W$

Comment: No. A *linear* map $T\colon V \to W$ induces a map from $k$-multilinear maps on $W$ to $k$-multilinear maps on $V$, for any $k$ whatsoever.

Comment: @TedShifrin: You're right, I edited; I was in a hurry, my bad.

Comment: @sidht: The linear map takes k-linear maps to k-linear maps, so the two k's must be the same.

Comment: @TedShifrin:I think T is a functional, f is the linear map. In any case this whole question has become too confused.

Comment: I added some notes in my edit, I don't know if you guys caught that. How else can I clarify?

Comment: @Rene: Yup, in my haste, I added to the confusion. I meant $f$, but typed $T$ out of linear habit. Sigh.